# PHP - DI container in a REST client

Tags: php, rest, dependencies, containers

I am trying to build a basic REST client in PHP as a way to make myself familiar with the concept of dependency injection container. Ultimately, I would like to do something like:

```
$client = new RestClient();
$client->getService('user', array('id, optional fields...'));
```

But I also want to be able to specify which object should handle the request (if I want to use fopen instead of curl, for instance).

According to what I've read so far, a proper way to achieve this would be:

```
$request = new ServiceDefinition( 
    'Curl', 
    array('...') 
); 
$user = new ServiceDefinition('User',  
    array(new ServiceReference('request')) 
); 
$container = new ServiceContainer(array( 
    'request' => $request, 
    'user'    => $user, 
));
```

My question is: is there a simpler way to build the dependency between the user object and the request object ? (a basic setter injection on RestClient(), maybe ?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your existing familiarity with Dependency Injection, using a DI container may be jumping in at the deep end. In short, it's certainly possible to substitute the container with simple setter injection:

```
interface HttpAdapterInterface {}
class CurlAdapter implements HttpAdapterInterface {}
class SocketAdapter implements HttpAdapterInterface {}

class RestClient {
    public function setHttpAdapter(HttpAdapterInterface $adapter) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Fabien Potencier has [a good series on DI](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection), the second part of which covers DI containers (and when to use them).

Comment: I still have a question if you don't mind. If I have a `getUser($id)` in my RestClient class function which returns a User object, how can I avoid the strong coupling between the RestClient and User classes if I don't use a DI container ?

Comment: That's where a DI container might work well. I'd have the User model take a container called something like `Resolver`, which essentially works as an adapter for how the User class gets by an ID. Then you have a concrete `RestClientResolver` which contains your REST client and knows how to use it to get users by an ID.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how you imagine a user instantiation considering your post above? Sorry if it sounds like a dumb request but I'm quite new to these good practices in oop.

Comment: [Here's a quick example](http://codepad.org/lOXPLN2b). Depending on the way the user model would be populated, it might be better to have all of those methods in `User` be static.